# How to prevent emacs hanging when 'accept-process-output' is called multiple times on a single process?

Tags: subprocess

I'm running into a bug where Emacs locks up when `accept-process-output` is being called on the same process multiple times.

In this case this is the `ispell-process`, however I don't think that matters so much.

Is there a way to detect if a process is 'in-use' to avoid multiple functions calling it at once?

---

Note some alternatives I've found which I'm not so happy with:

- Have a separate `ispell-process` which is set for cases where multiple callers may overlap.
- Use locking variables to avoid multiple callers using it at once.